# Correct handling of setTimeout in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a one-page web application, and in the main component's `ngOnInit()` function, it calls a function `loopDoSomething()` which is recursive, using `setTimeout`, like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Some operations
  this.loopDoSomething();
}

loopDoSomething() {
  // Some operations
  setTimeout(this.loopDoSomething.bind(this), 1500);
}
```

Should I add a stop condition to `loopDoSomething` or is that enough?

Basically what I'm asking is whether closing the page will automatically  stop the process running `loopDoSomething()`, or should I handle it manually, in the `ngOnDestroy()` function?

Comment: Yes, closing the browser window or tab will stop all the JS code running on that window/tab. You should probably use setInterval(), BTW, and use arrow function: `setInterval(() => this.doSomething(), 1500)`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! Btw, why should I use setInterval instead? what's the difference beside the code elegance?

Comment: are you getting a Observable from the recursive call?

Comment: That has nothing to do with angular. Thos are native JavaScript functions. setTimeout executes a function once, later. setInterval executes a function every N milliseconds. So you don't need to reschedule the next function call every time the function is called. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: @JBNizet thanks again. Changed the tagging to js only. (Sorry, I'm new to js and angular, as you can see)

Comment: @Aravind not in this case, why?

Comment: Do you mean actually closing the page or navigating away to another route?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz both cases

Comment: Ok, with setTimeouts I don't think you have to do anything, but with setInterval you should definitely clear it manually when destroying the component.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz why do I have to clear it woth setInterval ?

Comment: @cookya Because a setInterval keeps ticking if you navigate away. (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser itself is the compiler of your Javascript code and when you open a tab, it'll create something called DOM( Document Object Model) of your html document and a global object called window.

When you close your browser, all of these are of course destroyed because the browser itself is the host and host is gone.